# Getting a covariance matrix from a dataset including non-numerical variables in data.table

Tags: r, lapply, numeric

Data:

```
library(data.table)
df <- fread(
    "A   B   D  E  iso   year   
     1   A   1  NA ECU   2009   
     2   B   2  0  ECU   2009   
     3   D   3  0  BRA   2011   
     4   E   4  0  BRA   2011   
     5   D   7  NA ECU   2008   
     6   E   1  0  ECU   2008   
     7   A   3  2  BRA   2012   
     8   A   4  NA BRA   2012",
  header = TRUE
)
```

I used to achieve this by running:

```
df_cov <- df[,lapply(Filter(is.numeric,.SD),cov, na.rm=TRUE)]
```

But with R 4.x it does not seem to like this anymore. Did something change in the data.table syntax as well?

Comment: This code has never calculated a covariance matrix. `cov` does not have a `na.rm` argument. Your code works if you replace `cov` with `var`.

Comment: Ahhh.. You are absolutely right, I did change that. I did not consider that it could matter. So what if I need the covariance matrix instead of the variance?

Comment: Then you need to change your code. `cov` needs a matrix as input. Subset `df` to relevant columns and pass the result to `cov`. Something like `cov(na.omit(df[, Filter(is.numeric, .SD)]))`.

Comment: Or `cov(df[, Filter(is.numeric, .SD)], use = "pairwise.complete.obs")`.